# What does the word 'Joll' mean in 18th century English?

Tags: meaning, orthography, early-modern-english

What does *joll* mean in the following sentence?

> ... give him the upper or right hand, and walk not just even with him cheek be **joll**, but a little behind him, yet not so distant as that it shall be troublesome to him to speak to thee,...

<sup>Source: [Rules for Childrens Behaviour ...](http://www.wwnorton.com/college/english/nael/18century/topic_1/behave.htm)</sup>

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a typo or archaic spelling (*joll* for ***jowl***).

Comment: @FumbleFingers if it is an archaic spelling, why is it still off topic? Saying that, it would be useful to know where the sentence came from. I suppose I could Google it... Done: http://www.wwnorton.com/college/english/nael/18century/topic_1/behave.htm

Comment: @Mari-Lou: If the text itself is that old, one would expect the reader to have access to something like OED (which takes me to the entry for ***jowl*** when I search for ***joll***). If it's *not* that old, I'd call it a typo. Given the context in which one might reasonably expect to encounter the archaic spelling, I still think it's GR. We surely don't want ELU clogged up with questions about weird Chaucerian spellings for words which are still current with different orthography.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I don't have access to the Oxford English Dictionary, does that mean I can't ask questions about the meanings of archaic words?

Comment: @Mari-Lou: It means unless you've got other resources to hand, you're probably going to have a hard time reading Chaucer in the original! Seriously, this isn't about the word itself - it's about an archaic spelling. But anyone with the confidence to be tackling text such as OP cites would normally be expected to be sufficiently familiar with English to recognise ***cheek be joll*** as ***cheek by jowl*** in the context as given.

Comment: @FumbleFingers and perhaps the OP is unfamiliar with the word *jowl* itself? For a non-native speaker *joll* could have been *joal*, or *gioll* for all they knew.  If you are unfamiliar with its modern-day spelling, and its meaning, it's not unreasonable that the OP asks the question.

Comment: @Mari-Lou: What can I say? If you don't have even that level of familiarity with *current* English, why would you expect to be able to read ME texts without help (by which I *don't* mean membership of ELU).

Comment: Of course I'm defending someone who's probably gone off to have her dinner, while I'm battling on her behalf.

Comment: Guys, the probable source (dated 1701, see below) is interesting in that it's basically written in modern English, with this phrase as an exception.

Comment: @A.E: I see *"Put not thy hand in the presence of others to any part of thy body, not ordinarily discovered"* in the list of strictures. Not exactly "modern" English, but the sentiment itself doubtless still occurs to many today (when watching crotch-clutching rappers on stage, for example).

Answer (score 10):

It's the phrase 'cheek by jowl', which the OED lists under the entry for '[cheek](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/31127)':

> 5.a. ***cheek by jowl**; †**cheek by cheek** (In 6–7 cheek(e to jowl, by chole, jole, joll, gig(g by geoul, jowl, 7–8 jig(g by jowl, 9 cheek by chowl, for chowl, and jowl, Sc. cheek-for-chow, dial. jig-by-jow.) **Side by side; in the closest intimacy**.*

It's also listed under '[jowl | jole](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/101780)' (n1):

> 1.a. A jawbone, a ‘chaft’; a jaw; esp. the under jaw; pl. Jaws.
>
> 4. Here perhaps belongs the phrase cheek by jowl, in earlier usage cheek by cheek: see cheek n. 5a. In this the j form is known from 1577, which is somewhat earlier than it is known in sense 1   above. The 17th c. variants cheek by chole, chowl, agree in form better with jowl n.2   or . But it is probable that, by the time the phrase came into use, all three ns. were already felt as one. The following examples supplement those under cheek n.

and that refers to '[jowl | jole](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/101781)' (n2):

> The external throat or neck when fat or prominent; the pendulous flesh extending from the chops to the throat of a fat person, forming a ‘double’ chin; the dewlap of cattle; the crop or the wattle of a bird, etc.;

So the OED seems to be uncertain as to whether the 'jowl' in 'cheek by jowl' refers to the jaw, the neck, or the roll of fat which makes a 'double chin' - or even perhaps '[head](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/101782)'.

But 'walking cheek by jowl' definitely means walking very close together.

This is from [The School of Manners](http://www.wwnorton.com/college/english/nael/18century/topic_1/behave.htm), I'm guessing?

> Walking with thy Superior in the house or Garden, give him the upper or righthand, and walk not just even with him cheek be joll, but a little behind him, yet not so distant as that it shall be troublesome to him to speak to thee, or hard for thee to hear.

So Garretson is saying, when you're walking with someone more important than you, don't walk side-by-side with them as if you were their best buddy, instead walk a little bit behind them (but not so far behind that it's a pain in the arse for them to talk to you).

Answer (score 5):

This appears to be an old spelling of the still-current expression *cheek by jowl*, meaning "close together", or "right next to each other".

*Jowl* is not common outside that expression, but it does still exist, and means  "The external throat or neck when fat or prominent; the pendulous flesh extending from the chops to the throat of a fat person, forming a ‘double’ chin" (OED). It is most often used in writing, in a description of a character, particularly something like *with heavy jowls*.

Comment: It’s also quite common in the US (particularly in the South) as [hog jowl](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pork_jowl). The word always makes me think of angry [Ankuras](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Ankura), jowls aquiver and saliva aflutter.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps "jowl", as in cheek by jowl?